# Installed geany has no options

Tags: 12.04, geany

I'm new to geany IDE. I installed geany from ubuntu software centre, and the window has no options other than opening a new file. I can't file any preference, tools option too for configuring.

I heard it is a full fledged IDE. Also, from the screenshots available from the software center, it seems my Geany installation is missing almost everything.

I'm not able to post the screenshots, but my interface just has 3 buttons. create a new file, open an existing file and a quit button. Everything else is inactive. I accidentally closed the sidepane, and I can't find any options to bring back that too.

**EDIT**
[image: my geany window]

What am I missing in my Geany installation?

**PS:** I tried installing from source from geany website. But, it posted some error saying GTK files not found. But, I removed geany from software centre and reinstalled several times. It installed Geany without problems, but with afore mentioned problems, that is I have nothing in my interface.

Also, even after reinstalling, somehow Geany remembers to hide the sidepane by default, which I'm not able to see at all.

I also added Geany ppa repository manually for latest fixes, but still when I reinstall from software centre I get a plain blank Geany interface.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is a VERY BAD idea to separate the application menu from the application window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Geany installation is fine. Geany app menu is integrated to unity top bar(Global Menu).

To get menu hover the mouse to the top bar of unity.

Below is the image that shows menu not visible when mouse is not focused on unity top bar
[image]

When mouse hovered on unity top bar
[image]

Alternate way to bring up the menu is by using <kbd>F10</kbd> key.

To bring up sidebar press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>b</kbd>

Comment: such a naive mistake by me!